# Writing Correct Xpath In Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Here is the link of what I am trying to work on:

https://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/all/jackets

For example I want to find and click on the Wool Suit Black Pinstripe:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(text(),"Wool Suit Black Pinstripe")]').click()
```

This is what I've used, but selenium keeps throwing an exception. Could anyone point me in the right direction as to why this is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to change this to

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[text()[contains(.,'Black Pinstripe')]]").click()
```

Edit.: I've just realized that the text you send as example ("Wool Suit Black Pinstripe") is not all inside the same web element on the [website](https://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/all/jackets)

When you inspect the page, you can find out that "Wool Suit" is inside an div and "Black Pinstripe" is inside another div. This may be tricky but some websites just work this way.

Nevertheless, I've updated my answer to use only "Black Pinstripe" text, this way it will recognize the WebElement and click where you want.

If it still doesn't work you can also try link text methods.

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text("Black Pinstripe")
```

and

```
driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("Black Pinstripe")
```

Comment: this throws the same exception as before, the element cannot be located

Comment: I've just added some better explanation. Check if it helps you.